# Adding alpha channels to PHP GD Images

Tags: php, gd

I want to create an png image with transparency using the GD functions of PHP.
Specifically, I'm have text with different opacity levels (for anti-aliasing).
Using the following code I am able to create an alpha in the main part of the background:

```
//Create image
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
//Set background to opaque
imagecolortransparent($image, imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0));
```

Though it does properly create an alpha, in area the image has opacity levels that are not 0% or 100%, it makes black.
How can I correctly create the opacity levels of these areas in the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically, I'm have text with different opacity levels (for
>   anti-aliasing)

Using a different opacity level for text doesn't anti-alias it.  And there's no reason to do this since GD outputs anti-aliased text anyway.

**Example 1:** This creates an image with an opaque black background with white text at various opacity levels

```
// create image resource.
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 200);

// create image colours.
$black     = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$white_0   = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 0);
$white_25  = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 32);
$white_50  = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 64);
$white_75  = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 96);
$white_100 = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 127);

// set background to opaque black.
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $black);

// output text strings.
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 30,  $white_0,   'arial.ttf', '0% transparent');
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 60,  $white_25,  'arial.ttf', '25% transparent');
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 90,  $white_50,  'arial.ttf', '50% transparent');
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 120, $white_75,  'arial.ttf', '75% transparent');
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 150, $white_100, 'arial.ttf', '100% transparent'); // not visible!

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

**Result 1:**

[image: example code 1 result]

**Example 2:** If what you want is a transparent background:

```
// create image resource.
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 200);
// save alpha channel information (for transparent background).
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);

// create image colours.
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
$black_0     = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$black_25    = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 32);
$black_50    = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 64);
$black_75    = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 96);

// set background to transparent.
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $transparent);

// output text strings.
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 30,  $black_0,   'arial.ttf', '0% transparent');
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 60,  $black_25,  'arial.ttf', '25% transparent');
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 90,  $black_50,  'arial.ttf', '50% transparent');
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 120, $black_75,  'arial.ttf', '75% transparent');
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 150, $transparent, 'arial.ttf', '100% transparent'); // not visible!

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

**Result 2:**

[image: example code 2 result]

Comment: Thanks... This would work, however, I'm using a logo build in GIMP with special features that I can't create using GD...

Comment: Ok, in that case I really don't understand what you're asking for.  Please update your question with example images of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Odd... Its suddenly working. Thanks for the help and sorry my question was so difficult to understand.